# "У тебя" or "твоё"

Tags: родительный-падеж, possessive-adjective, притяжательные-местоимения

While translating the sentence:"what is your favorite animal?" from English I would rather say in Russian:

> Какое твоё любимое животное?

but it turned out that the correct translation is

> Какое у тебя любимое животное?

What is the logic and other cases wherein the use of possessive pronoun in English does not correspond to an equivalent use of the possessive pronoun in Russian?

Comment: In casual situations both variants are valid. The first one is incorrect possibly because of presence "Какое", so without "Какое" the question is correct.